# How to change the title of a button inside a cell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collection view and inside a button.
When I tap this button I want to change its name.
I managed to do it but when I tap it, it changes if I have 20 buttons 10 of them like this if I tap the first button it changes the 0,2,4,6,8 and if I tap a button which isn't in the list then all buttons are checked.

This is my code:

```
 @IBAction func following(sender: AnyObject) {
        if follow.tag == sender.tag {
        follow.setTitle("Following", forState: .Normal)
        }
        print("\(follow.tag) \(sender.tag)")
    }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Interest Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ThirdTabCell

        cell.follow.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell



        }
```

Inside button's function I tried without if statement too but again the same problem.
When I print the tags it prints only the button which was tapped.

I also tried this to my ViewController

```
  cell.follow.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ThirdTab.follow(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) 
//inside cellForItemAtIndexPath

     func follow(sender:UIButton!) {



        }
```

Comment: May I ask where is following()? Cause you shouldn't be able to have an IBAction from reusable cells. Also, I assume sender should be UIButton instead of AnyObject?

Comment: the ibaction func is inside cell class

Comment: I would suggest you to create a selector method in your VC.

Comment: I had a function in my regular class for the button but i didn't know how can i change only one button in 1 minute i will edit my question to see what i have

Comment: When you cellForItemAtIndexPath, do followButton. followButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myClass.follow(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 3):

**Just a short overview, So you get your answer**

UICollectionView is highly optimized, and thus only keep On-screen visible rows in memory. Now, All rows Cells are cached in Pool and are reused and not regenerated. Whenever, user scrolls the UICollectionView, it adds the just-hidden rows in Pool and reuses them for next to be visible rows.

**So, now, coming to your answer**

When you tap on button, its title will get updated, but when you will scroll your collection view, the same cell with "updated button text" will be reused and *that will cause the issue you are seeing.*

**SOLUTION**

SAVE button state in an array, in your action method

```
@IBAction func following(sender: AnyObject) {
        if follow.tag == sender.tag {
          array[sender.tag] = "<text>"
          collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        print("\(follow.tag) \(sender.tag)")
    }
```

and inside your datasource method
update your button text like below:

**//trick is to update your button text for each index**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
   //SAMPLE CODE
   let buttonValue = array[indexPath.index]

  // update button value for each index
  //trick is to update your button text for each index    
   cell.button.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
 }
```

Comment: it didn't work...I will try some changes and I will inform you

Comment: sure, but would like to know - which part didn't work?

Comment: How can all this be in one View Controller if you aren't allowed to link elements inside a collection view into anything but the Collection View Cell file?

Comment: Jevon, I suggested "everything in viewcontroller" above, because OP's question had all targeted code written in view controller! I prefer, linking elements inside CollectionViewCell and then call ViewController using delegate! So, it is not mandatory to have everything in viewController! Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Please change below the set title line in following function.

Existing Line:

```
follow.setTitle("Following", forState: .Normal)
```

New Line:

```
follow.setTitle("Following", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Hope this is working for you.

Thanks

Comment: You can just .Normal for enumerations in Swift now. Having UIControlState. now doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to approach it this way.

Inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you can assign a buttons outlet like this

```
cell.followOutlet.tag = indexPath.row
```

and then inside your follow function you can do this

```
@IBAction func following(sender: AnyObject) {
        let follow = sender as! UIButton
        let indexP = NSIndexPath(forRow: follow.tag, inSection: 0)
        let cell = yourCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexP) as! yourCellName

        follow.setTitle("Following", forState: .Normal)

    }
```

And now you can do whatever you want with your button.

Comment: No again the same problem